# Google Maps Api

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

i'm having a problem with Google Maps api integration for form autocomplete.
I have implemented it and works properly until i try to restrict by country.

```
<script>
function initialize() {

var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
new google.maps.LatLng(40.802089, -124.163751)
);

var origin_input = document.getElementById('location');
//var isocode = document.getElementById('ISOcountry').val()

var options = {
bounds: defaultBounds,
types: ['(cities)'],
language: '<?php echo $lang['dataLanguage']?>',
//componentRestrictions: {country: isocode }
};


var autocomplete_origin = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(origin_input, options);    
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

if i uncomment the 2 lines for componetRestrictions it doesn't work and i don't understand why.

```
var isocode = document.getElementById('ISOcountry').val()
```

get the ISO country value from here:

Do you guys have any idea?

Also i would like to optimize the script getting the ISO code directly from another script attached here:

```
$.post('libs/jsonISOcountry.php', { country : val }, populateISOcountry, 'html');
function populateISOcountry(data) {
    $('#ISOcountry').html(data);
}
```

Content of the page jsonISOcountry.php

```
//....DB connection.....
if (!empty($_POST['country'])) {
foreach ($conn->query("SELECT * FROM regions WHERE countryID=".$_POST['country']) as    $row3) {
$html = $row3['isocountry'] ; 

}
die($html);
```

Thanks in advance for you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the issue!

```
var isocode = document.getElementById('ISOcountry').val()
```

wasn't working on hidden field of the form!

changed with this one and working properly!

```
var isocode = document.getElementById('ISOcountry').value;
```